# How to enable space-based line-wrapping in JTextPane?

Tags: java, swing, jtextpane, word-wrap

Is it possible to enable space-based line-wrapping in a JTextPane?

Using a JTextArea is not an option because I need to style the content.

Comment: This is the default behaviour of a JTextPane. That is if an entire word won't fit on the line then it is wrapped at the previous space. If you are having a problem then post your [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) that demonstrates the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how you make a default JFrame with a JTextPane and line-wrap. As said by camickr, this is the default behaviour.

```
package test;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JTextPane;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
/**
 *
 * @author floz
 */
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                final JFrame mainFrame = new JFrame("test");
                mainFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                final JTextPane field = new JTextPane();
                field.setText("qds qljsd qsld qlskd qlkds fqlk sdkf qlskdfqlk sdlf qsld ql sdf qlskd fqks lqksjd f");

                mainFrame.getContentPane().setLayout(new BorderLayout());
                mainFrame.getContentPane().add(field,BorderLayout.CENTER);
                mainFrame.setSize(200,200);
                mainFrame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could add a listener to the **JTextPane** document that does the line wrapping like follows:

```
    pane.getDocument().addDocumentListener(new DocumentListener()
    {

          @Override
          public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent e) 
          {
               if(e.getOffset() >= pane.getSize().getWidth() / pane.getFont().getSize())
               {
                     String str = pane.getText();
                     if(str.length() <= str.lastIndexOf(32))
                     {
                           try 
                           {
                                e.getDocument().insertString(str.lastIndexOf(32), "\n", pane.getCharacterAttributes());

                           } catch (BadLocationException e1) 
                           {
                                e1.printStackTrace();
                           }
                     }
               }                
          }

          @Override
          public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {}

          @Override
          public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {}

   });
```

Comment: What if the frame is resized causing the text pane to also be resized? Or what if multiple lines of text are pasted into the text pane? Now the hardcoded lines breaks will prevent the text from readjusting.

Comment: @camickr: Well then he should put some own afford into that?! The question didn't mention responsive to resizing. I just gave him a basic idea of solving that.

Comment: And this is why it is usually good practice to separate the model from the view.